# Generate variable based on grouped row-wise comparisons over several columns in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table, panel-data

I'm using R Studio version 4.0.1 on Windows. I have unbalanced panel data in a `data.table` containing 256 variables and 8,278 observations. The data are uniquely identified by `ID` for specific companies and `period` for specific points in time. Additionally, in columns `102:162` I got different region dummies (2= yes, company operates in region; 1= no, company does not operate in region) that also include `NA`s. Below is a small exemplary dataset.

**Exemplary data**

```
dat <- 
data.table(ID = as.factor(c(rep("C001", 3), "C002", rep("C003", 5), rep("C004", 2), rep("C005", 7))),
period = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
region1 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region2 = as.factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, 2, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region3 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2, rep(NA, 7))),
region4 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region5 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA, 2, 1, 2, rep(NA, 7))))

#      ID period region1 region2 region3 region4 region5
# 1: C001      1       1       1       1       1       1
# 2: C001      2       1       2       1       1       1
# 3: C001      3       2       1       2       1       1
# 4: C002      2       1       1       1       2       2
# 5: C003      1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 6: C003      4       1       1       1       1       1
# 7: C003      5       2       2       1       1       2
# 8: C003      6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 9: C003     10       1       2       1       1       2
#10: C004      3       1       1       1       1       1
#11: C004      4       1       1       2       1       2
#12: C005      2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#13: C005      3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#14: C005      4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#15: C005      7    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#16: C005      8    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#17: C005      9    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#18: C005     10    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

**Problem description**

I want to find out if a company entered a market it was not active in before. For this, I need to compare the region dummies (i.e. each of the variables in columns `102:162`) from `period` t with `period` t+1, t+1 with t+2, t+2 with t+3, etc. by company (i.e. `ID`).

I want `market_entry == "yes"` in the period in which a company started operations in a region it was not active in before. This is the case e.g. if in `period` t at least one variable of `102:162 == 1` and in t+1 the same variable(s) of `102:162 == 2`. I want `market_entry == "no"` in the period in which a company did not start any operations in any new region. This is the case if in `period` t at least one variable of `102:162 == 1` and in t+1 the same variable(s) of `102:162 == 1` AND if in `period` t at least one variable of `102:162 == 2` and in t+1 the same variable(s) of `102:162 == 2`. I want `market_entry == NA` in the period in which the specific region dummy states `NA`. If for a specific company there are information for e.g. `period`s 5 and 7 but `period` 6 states `NA`, then `period`s 5 and 7 should be compared. It might also be that there are information for e.g. `period`s 5 and 10 but `period` 6  states `NA` and there are no information at all about `period`s 7-9 (i.e. observations 7-9 in the exemplary dataset above). Then `period`s 5 and 10 should be compared.
If the first observation in `102:162 == 2` for a specific company, then `market_entry` must equal `NA` because we don't know if the company entered the market just in this period (e.g. t+4) or in a previous one.

Since companies can enter and leave the markets several times throughout the whole observation period, the code needs to also start again from t+1 looking at t+2, from t+2 looking at t+3, from t+3 looking at t+4, etc. Below there is an exemplary desired output.

**Desired output**

```
desired_output <- 
data.table(ID = as.factor(c(rep("C001", 3), "C002", rep("C003", 5), rep("C004", 2), rep("C005", 7))),
period = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
region1 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region2 = as.factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, 2, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region3 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2, rep(NA, 7))),
region4 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region5 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA, 2, 1, 2, rep(NA, 7))),
market_entry = as.factor(c("no", "yes", "yes", NA, NA, "no", "yes", NA, "no", "no", "yes", rep(NA, 7))))

#      ID period region1 region2 region3 region4 region5 market_entry
# 1: C001      1       1       1       1       1       1           no -> company not in any region
# 2: C001      2       1       2       1       1       1          yes -> company entered region2
# 3: C001      3       2       1       2       1       1          yes -> company entered region1 and region3 (but left region 2 which is not of any importance here)
# 4: C002      2       1       1       1       2       2         <NA> -> first information from period 2, we don't know whether company already entered region4 and region5 in prior period
# 5: C003      1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA> -> no information
# 6: C003      4       1       1       1       1       1           no -> company not in any region
# 7: C003      5       2       2       1       1       2          yes -> company entered region1, region2 and region5
# 8: C003      6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA> -> no information
# 9: C003     10       1       2       1       1       2           no -> ignore NA in period 6 and lack of information for periods 7-9; compare observations 7 and 9: no new market entry (left region1 which is not of any importance here)
#10: C004      3       1       1       1       1       1           no -> company not in any region
#11: C004      4       1       1       2       1       2          yes -> company entered region3 and region5
#12: C005      2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#13: C005      3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#14: C005      4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#15: C005      7    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#16: C005      8    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#17: C005      9    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
#18: C005     10    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
```

Any hints are highly appreciated since I don't have any idea of where to start (except for using `dplyr` to group the data by `ID`).

Comment: You said *"yes" in the period* if a region is 1 in that period and 2 in the next period, yet `C001` and `region2` is "no" in row 1 (which is a "1" with "2" in the next row). I suspect your wording should be something like *"yes" if a 2 in a period and a 1 in the previous period* (or such).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was always thinking about it that way but at some point thought it would be easier to grab when starting with the first period looking at later ones after. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
dat[, market_entry := if (nrow(.SD) > 1) {
  rowSums(sapply(.SD, function(z) {
    zoo::rollapplyr(z, 2, FUN = function(x) identical(as.character(x), c("1","2")), fill = FALSE)
  }))  > 0 } else FALSE,
  by=.(ID), .SDcols = patterns("region")]
#         ID period region1 region2 region3 region4 region5 market_entry
#     <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>       <lgcl>
#  1:   C001      1       1       1       1       1       1        FALSE
#  2:   C001      2       1       2       1       1       1         TRUE
#  3:   C001      3       2       1       2       1       1         TRUE
#  4:   C002      2       1       1       1       2       2        FALSE
#  5:   C003      1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
#  6:   C003      4       1       1       1       1       1        FALSE
#  7:   C003      5       2       2       1       1       2         TRUE
#  8:   C003      6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
#  9:   C003     10       1       2       1       1       2        FALSE
# 10:   C004      3       1       1       1       1       1        FALSE
# 11:   C004      4       1       1       2       1       2         TRUE
# 12:   C005      2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 13:   C005      3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 14:   C005      4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 15:   C005      7    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 16:   C005      8    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 17:   C005      9    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
# 18:   C005     10    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        FALSE
```

Walk-through:

- the meat of the operation is done with `zoo::rollapplyr`, which looks at two cells (within a column) at a time; I add `fill=FALSE` to make sure it always returns the same length as the input vector (default is to return partial vectors, incompatible with frames);
- `rowSums(.) > 1` is essentially *"if any of the regions is true, then true"*;
- `if (nrow(.SD) > 1)` is required because `sapply` will return a matrix (which is good) unless `.SD` has only one row, which will cause `rowSums` to fail; since we know that a 1-row group cannot meet your constraints, it's an easy `else FALSE`;
- internally, `identical(as.character(x), c("1","2"))` is a little bit of a hack: comparing factors from different columns can be a risk, since "1" and "2" (strings) may have different integers in different columns, so I force strings.
- ... and I group `by=.(ID)`, and only run that `rowSums(sapply(.))` process on the columns with names that match `patterns("region")`.
- I am assuming that the order of `period` is increasing within each `ID`.
- I am not looking for potential gaps in `period`, not sure if that's possible or meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for this approach and the explanations, r2evans! Still need to get my head around of how to include the required ``NA``s in ``market_entry``. Further, I face the (minor) problem that other variables that I don't want to consider here also include "region" as pattern. Regarding your explanation on ``if (nrow(.SD) > 0)`` I suppose you meant ``if (nrow(.SD) > 1)``, right? Indeed, ``period`` is (except for very few duplicates that hopefully don't cause any problems) increasing within each ``ID``.

Comment: `nrow(.SD) > 1` yes, not sure why I made that mistake (though it was only in the documentation, not the code, whew!). As for `region` in other variables, recall that you can use a `character` vector there instead of `patterns`, so feel free to preface that whole command with `mycolnames <- grep("...", names(date)); mycolnames <- ...` (other filtering steps) in order to make it what you need it to be.

Comment: (`s/date/dat/` above ...)